# Camera.WorldToScreenPoint not working with perspective

Tags: unity, camera, gui

```
transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint( new Vector3( origin.position.x, origin.position.y, origin.position.z ) );
```

I have this code on a Unity 4.6 UI object. The origin is some transform I want the UI element to stay above( like a floating health bar ).

The camera is top-down, but angled slightly on the x-axis. When the camera is moved, the UI element moves away from the origin slightly as if the camera was orthographic.

How would I go about compensating for the perspective? Is there another method I should be using to convert from world space to canvas space?

EDIT: Pictures added. Note that the transform is at the center of the model, not the base.
[image]

Comment: Please cleatify what you want to do.

Comment: You have to just subtract y coordinate from Screen.height please check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You want to move 2d UI (Label) with respect to your game object. **WorldToScreenPoint** transform the position from world space into screen space.

**Here you are on right track, what you are missing is that**

```
screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
screenPosition.y = Screen.height - screenPosition.y;
```

So, according to me your script like this:

```
var screenPosition :  Vector3;

function Update (){
    screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    screenPosition.y = Screen.height - screenPosition.y;
}

function OnGUI (){ 
    GUI.Label(Rect(screenPosition.x, screenPosition.y, 50, 20),"Health...");   

}
```

Or you can use this script:
**Ready to use Script (Tested & works )**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;


public class SingleLbl : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool mShowGUIButton = false;
    public GameObject targetObject;
    public float btnWidth = 400f;
    public float btnHeight = 180f;



    void Start () {

    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        // Find the 2D position of the object using the main camera
        Vector3 boxPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(targetObject.transform.position);

        // "Flip" it into screen coordinates
        boxPosition.y = Screen.height - boxPosition.y;

        // Center the label over the coordinates
        //boxPosition.x -= boxW * 0.5f;
        //boxPosition.y -= boxH * 0.5f;

        GUI.Button(new Rect(boxPosition.x, boxPosition.y, btnWidth , btnHeight), targetObject.name);
        Debug.Log (boxPosition.z + "--x--" + boxPosition.x + "----y--" + boxPosition.y);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, man. Also thanks for reminding me about this question. However, I made a stupid mistake and didn't realise the transform origin is actually at his feet, meaning it's working perfectly. I'll delete this question soon.

Comment: :) at first me too do the same..never mind.. .but other ll learn from it

Answer (score 0):

would it be better for you to add a object you can reference as a child of the game object.  It could be damage1 or something and then on a trigger you could

`Instantiate(damage1, transform.position, transform.rotation);`

you could then set that to a animation effect like moving up and fading out or whatever effect you like.

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem. The GUI isn't in world space. Setting the position isn't the problem, the conversion from world space to screen space is.

Comment: Are you just trying to add a damage effect? like he gets hit and it show -1 damage text. I was suggesting another way to implement without all the worldspace to screenspace calculations.

Comment: Yeah. I don't understand how this would solve the problem, though. We want the text to be on the a child of the canvas, not a world space object.

Comment: damage1 would be gameobject with a TextMesh and animation on it in the example I showed. you would get your desired effect. but if you must have it a child of the canvas then sorry for suggesting a method that doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I should have clarified, I'd much prefer to use the new Unity UI stuff. A TextMesh seems a bit unnecessary here.

Comment: I prefer using the new UI for lots of stuff but damage and point effects I been using the still useful text mesh :) Another suggestion would be to assign your text to a canvas set to world space.

Answer (score -1):

you can add this to the update function of your UI object:

```
transform.forward = -Camera.main.gameObject.transform.forward;
```

Comment: This just seems to mess up the GUI element.